# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSString,when application is brought to foreground from background [ on 4.0 OS ]

Tags: iphone

Currently My application is getting crashed on accessing NSString after bringing application to foreground from background [on 4.0 OS].

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

iDatabasePath  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:KApp_DB_Name];
```

iDatabasePath is declared as NSString* and it is globally declared.

When Application is moved to background and brought to foreground when I make a call to

```
 iDatabasePath  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:KApp_DB_Name];
```

Application crashes due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS to iDatabasePath and this is happening on 4.0 OS

Please help me on this.

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 0):

you need to retain it...

`[iDatabasePath retain]` somewhere - probably `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: I did that, but no use. still it gives me bad access.

Comment: what about retaining documentsDirectory? and/or paths?

Comment: If I try to retain those on applicationDidEnterBackground I get error -[NSPathStore2 retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: hmm... try looking up NSZombiesEnabled. This might help you debug. It sounds like the object is running its dealloc method, and thus releasing your pointers before applicationDidEnterBackground gets called.

Answer (score 0):

so which line is the error on? If its on the line you say, it looks like `documentsDirectory` would be getting released, not `iDatabasePath`, have you tried to retain iDatabasePath?

Comment: it is giving me error on iDatabasePath  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:KApp_DB_Name];  but if I make iDatabasePath local then it works.